# Операции с DOM инициированные перезагрузкой страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, расширения

Здравствуйте! Разрабатываю расширение браузера для Chrome. В основе - JavaScript + jQuery. На сайте есть кнопка, которая через онклик производит AJAX - перезагрузку страницы:

```
<button onclick="return m.pageReload()">
```

Через строку в расширении

```
$('[onclick="return m.pageReload()"]').click(function(){ ... });
```

Требуется внести изменения DOM на *перезагруженной странице*. Тем не менее функция вызывающаяся `.click` выполняется раньше перезагрузки страницы, выполняются на старой странице и изменения через приблизительно 100 милисекунд перезагружаются вместе со старой страницей. т.е. на перезагруженной, где они мне нужны, их нет. Не подскажите как можно решить такую проблему, т.е. в функции относящейся к  `.click` определить, что страница уже перезагружена?
Заранее благодарен.

Comment: когда "страница перезагружена" - никакой "функции относящейся к  .click" уже нет

Comment: Можно добавить в `localStorage` признак, необходимо ли вам выполнять действие при загрузке страницы. Если признак стоит, то выполнить действия и признак удалить.

Comment: Вероятно я неправильно выразился. Имеется в виду что будет перезагружена информация в конкретном блоке, а не на всей странице. Ну а если всё равно это не тот метод, был бы очень рад указанию как решить проблему вызова собственной функции при нажатии кнопки расширением, работающей после родной.

Comment: Вопрос в том, как привязать этот признак к окончанию родной функции?